# How to return a DataFrame when using pandas.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I'm trying to get a concated DataFrame using pandas.apply(), there is a demo below:

[image]

Just like the code shown, the `apply()` returns a Series instead of a concated DataFrame that I expected, how can I solve it?

Comment: please provide your code as **text**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `df.applymap()`?
Tecnically, they do the same thing but the `applymap` apply your function to the entire Dataframe and it returns a Dataframe no matter what happens.